# Integrate GrapesJS with React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grapesjs

I am trying to integrate GrapesJS Feature with my React APP.

```
I get an error while implementing like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined grapesjs react`

I would like to have a feature like in this URL

https://grapesjs.com/demo.html



npm i grapesjs-react

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import GEditor from 'grapesjs-react';

class GEditorExample extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
         <GEditor/>
     );
   }
}

export default GEditorExample;
```

- How can I get this feature for my react app to build HTML Web Builder.

Any help would be great.
Thank You.*

Comment: Try re-running after `npm install grapesjs`

Answer (score 2):

You've to specify the blocks prop to , this block will be added to the editor by `blockmanager.add` method of grapes-js.
If there is no need for a block, try giving an empty array, like:

```
<GEditor id="gjs" blocks={[]} />
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. just last question. How can I store the data into Database ? Is there any Storage Manager or Storage API so that I can use it with my React Component.

Thank You.

Comment: You can pass a URL to use as storage manager on `init`. By default, grapesjs uses local storage for this. The documentation would be helpful to know more about storage manager [grape](https://grapesjs.com/docs/modules/Storage.html#basic-configuration)

Comment: I am using it with react JS. so How can I implement it ?

Comment: My usecase is if my client designs a template then he should be able to white-label it to send to his clients.

Comment: 'grapesjs-react' calls the storage manager object on init internally. I come across a similar problem by creating react wrapper around 'grapesjs', similar to 'grapesjs-react' and passing the storage manager there.

Comment: @Vishnu, may I ask you to have a look at a GrapesJS related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679919/grapesjs-and-php-store-and-load-data-to-show-in-editor-and-as-html-page-as-wel ?

Answer (score 1):

if You pass blocks to GEditor, It will work.

See the sample code below

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import GEditor from 'grapesjs-react';

class GEditorExample extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
          <GEditor id="geditor"  blocks={[]}/>
     );
   }
}

export default GEditorExample;
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of grapesjs-react are you using?
I configured the default value for `blocks` props:

```js
GEditor.defaultProps = {
  blockManager: {},
  blocks: [],
  components: [],
  newsletter: false,
  plugins: [],
  storageManager: {},
  styleManager: {},
  webpage: false,
};
```

Try to update the package to the newest version if you still got this error.

Comment: I use 2.0.0 of grapesjs-react

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a good integrator for a while. Currently, my solution is to use `<iframe>` to load GrapeJS from an external file server. For example: using an iframe inside a React component like this:

`` <iframe height="100%" src={`http://127.0.0.1:8081/templateId=${templateId} title="Build your own template" width="100%" /> ``

I know it's not a good solution, but currently its the only method I found to be workable with my problem.

Comment: Please provide more details to your answer.

Comment: may I ask you to have a loook at a GrapesJS related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679919/grapesjs-and-php-store-and-load-data-to-show-in-editor-and-as-html-page-as-wel ?